# Not Able to Upload 2 Kb File Properly Using IFromFile object In ASP Dot net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

**Here is my code :**

```
        try
        {
          string basedirecotry = _env.WebRootPath; //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
          string filePath = basedirecotry + "\\images\\services\\";
          filePath = filePath + file.FileName;

          file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
          return Json("/images/services/" + file.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("0");
        }
```

File is created to specified path but file size is 0 Kb.but if I m uploading File Size greater than 30 Kb it's working File I Don't know exctly that less than 30 Kb worked or not.
Also i don't have any configuration in appconfig as well.

Can any one help me in this ?

Comment: Acually I have tested there is issue with less than 5 kb file for upload using IFromFile Object.

Answer (score 1):

I found One solution for this using FormFileExtension I am able to save less then 5 kb file successfully.